# Is this a correct summary of Phonegap notification terminology?

Tags: notifications, push-notification, phonegap-build

I am building mobile apps for iOS and Android using PhoneGap Build. In my simplest apps I was using the word 'notification' to mean the messages similar to Javascript's `alert()` displayed immediately to the user within the webview. This is `navigator.notification.alert()`

Now I need to build a more complicated app (using plugins) which can display messages in a device's general notification area, when my app is not in the foreground.

[image: Examples]

There seems to be several phrases I am not sure I understand correctly...

1. **Local Notifications**: the app decides when to create these, and they can be scheduled for future dates. They will display regardless of the app being running/background/terminated.
2. **Remote Notifications**: a server decides when to create these, and they are sent to the app by a service controlled by Apple or Google. Also called **Push Notifications**. They will also display regardless of the app being running/background/terminated.
3. Is there a **third type** of homebrew notification where the app makes a HTTP call to a server every 10 minutes, and creates a notification when it receives instructions to do so? This is called 'pull' I suppose. It will only work when the app is still running in the background (unless you make use of the BackgroundFetch plugin, which is Android only).

**Is the above correct?** What have I misunderstood? Is the third type prone to problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

essentially correct. You should also know that the word *Notification* has been corrupted into these meanings. The terms previously used are lost to me.

On #3, the so-called "pull" method is often prostituted to mean "push" notifications. You will often hear, *the "pull" method is a backup when the "push" method fails* -- and even this is a corruption. They meant to say, *if an older mobile phone was encountered and there was a defect in the library to keep the socket open, we will use the* ***"polling method"*** (aka pull method).

In addition, the corruption was originally an issue with push notification systems, like group-on and urban airship. The terms have floated into the realm of MBaaS (Mobile Backend as a Service) and RTMaaS (Real Time Messaging as a Service).

- MBass = Firebase, etc
- RTMaas = pubhub, etc.

Nice work. I'm bookmarking your comments.